# Select current element and change values on click

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm new to Javascript and I've been trying to program a code that changes the value of an attribute and a style when its element is clicked. I have this code and I want that when you click on "`<li class="has-sub">`" it changes to "`<li class="has-sub show">`"... and inside it, that "`<ul class="sub-menu m-sub" style="display: none;">`" changes to "`<ul class="sub-menu m-sub" style="display: block;">`":

```
<li class="has-sub">
  <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu m-sub" style="display: none;">
    <li>
      <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="submenu-toggle"></div>
</li>
```

When clicked, it should look like this:

```
<li class="has-sub show">
  <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu m-sub" style="display: block;">
    <li>
      <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="submenu-toggle"></div>
</li>
```

I have made the attempt on my own, and tried to place this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(document).ready(function change() {
    $(this).attr('has-sub','has-sub show');
    $(this > ul).css('display','block');
  })
</script>
```

And call the function with "onclick":

```
<li class="has-sub" onclick"change();">
```

But I haven't been able to achieve it yet...

Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the parent to toggle a class that has `display: none` applied to it. `$(this).children('ul').toggleClass('hide')` will target the class hide and then toggle its class on click using `toggleClass()`. Set the `hide` class by default on the HTML `sub-menu` element.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.has-sub').on('click', function(){
       $(this).children('ul').toggleClass('hide')
    })
})
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="has-sub show">
  <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu m-sub hide">
    <li>
      <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="submenu-toggle"></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to add click listener on `.has-sub` and after that you can add class `show`.

- You need to add class `show`. It is not an attribute.
- Just use `.has-sub > ul` to get the `ul` that is direct child of `.has-sub`.

```js
$(document).ready(function change() {
  // $(this).attr("has-sub", "has-sub show");

  $(".has-sub").click(function() {
    $(this).addClass("show");
    $(".has-sub > ul").css("display", "block");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li class="has-sub">
  <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
  <ul class="sub-menu m-sub" style="display: none;">
    <li>
      <a href="#" role="menuitem">Hi</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div class="submenu-toggle"></div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this as click handler, then you can remove the `onclick"change();"`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".has-sub > a").on("click", function() {
    // here you can use
    // - $(this).parent() to do something with the li.has-sub
    // - $(this).next("ul") to do something with the ul.sub-menu
  });
});
```